# What are ways to measure light scattering for a science fair project? And how exactly does scattering work?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering

How does scattering work? And why?

I am still in middle school. I am doing my science fair project on scattering and so far the resources I found have either oversimplified it or made it in a way that I don't understand.

I know that white light comes in and meets particles. It interacts with these particles by either refracting, reflecting, or scattering, and many others that I don't begin to understand yet. I know that scattering happens by when the light is deflected or diffused away from a particle, but I know there is more and I need to know it.

Also, I was wondering what you think is the best way to measure/graph the amount of scattering there was based on the amount of particulates in a liquid for my project? I was thinking of measuring the amount of energy that leaves the tank (my sky). I would measure it with a machine that measures energy through a solar cell, but that will only pick up the light emitted, not the heat. Do you think that matters?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a great site for physics Q&A. Part of what makes it great is that we have pretty high standards for questions. One of the most important rules is that each post should try to ask a single focused question. This post has two different questions: 1) how scattering works, and 2) how to measure it. I would recommend splitting this up into two separate posts. The problem with asking two questions at once is that a would-be answerer has to comprehend two questons, know the answers to both, and take the time to write *two* answers instead of one.

Comment: For your level measuring the flux with a solar cell is perfectly fine. Don't worry about the spectral distribution and the details. What you may want to worry about is the calibration for the total amount of light that hits your tank, so take one measurement of the direct light and one measurement of the scattered light and work with the ratio between scattered and direct.